# How can I deploy my asp.net core app to a windows 10 IOT device from vs 2015 community edition

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to get my asp.net core website deployed to my windows 10 iot core device(raspbery pi 2). I'm sure there is a way to do this in some manual process, but all my googling has turned up nothing.

Comment: Would you find this post helpful? https://www.hackster.io/iddi/windows-10-iot-core-publish-asp-net-web-application-d9dcd4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some Googling I found my problem was two fold.

1. I didn't add the Universal Windows App features when I installed VS2015

   - you must add Tools 1.4.1
   - windows 10 SDK(10.0.xxxxx)
2. Install Windows IOT Core Templates

   - https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/55b357e1-a533-43ad-82a5-a88ac4b01dec

Once I did this the standard Microsoft documentation worked perfectly.
   - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/appdeployment

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use the Universal Windows Platform extension to develop apps for Windows 10 IoT Core. Which I don't think is available in Visual Studio Community. This may have changed.

Here's a couple of links to get you started:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/layout/design-and-ui-intro

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/universal-windows-platform-vs.aspx

Once you've got a UWP app you can extend the framework to use .Net Core. This blog post talks about it more: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/27/making-it-easier-to-port-to-net-core/

Hope this helps.